# Copying status panel icon for diodon

Tags: wingpanel, icons

I've installed the clipboard manager diodon, a status panel applet I've used before with Ubuntu that works very well. The only annoyance is that in elementary it doesn't use a monochrome icon, but rather the default, colored icon.

I found some [instructions](https://esite.ch/2014/07/where-is-my-diodon-monochrome-icon/) for changing the icon manually which basically included copying the icon from `/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/status/22` to my own theme's icon folder. Since elementary didn't appear to have 22px resolution icons, I copied from and to the 24 folders instead. But this didn't have any effect, the panel applet icon is still the same as before, even after having run `sudo gtk-update-icon-cache /usr/share/icons/elementary/`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why it didn't work, but I'd suggest you try [elementary+](https://github.com/mank319/elementaryPlus).

> elementary+ is a community maintained addition to elementary OS's
>   default icon theme. It contains icons for several third party
>   applications that resemble elementary OS's style.

While it may not have many application icons, this theme contains almost every indicator icon:

[image: indicator icons]

[image: application icons]